# create XML inline xmlns

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm working in Python using lxml to create XML output, the final project will require the xml to be imported into Strava, I therefore need the schema correct before it will import. Below is the schema I have created, my issue is that I cannot seem to get the formatting right if I include the XMLNS text as shown below.

```
<Extensions>
   <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
    <Speed>0.0</Speed>
   </TPX>
</Extensions>
```

My code so far is:

```
def Trackpoint():
    E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
    Trackpoint = E.Trackpoint
    Time = E.Time
    Postion = E.Postion
    LatitudeDegrees = E.LatitudeDegrees
    LongitudeDegrees = E.LongitudeDegrees
    AltitudeMeters = E.AltitudeMeters
    DistanceMeters = E.DistanceMeters
    Cadence = E.Cadence
    Extensions = E.Extensions
    TPX = E.TPX
    Speed = E.Speed

    the_doc = Trackpoint(
        Time('2017-11-23T20:44:33Z'),
        Postion(
            LatitudeDegrees('32.2996560'),
            LongitudeDegrees('-64.7868500'),
        ),
        AltitudeMeters('16.4'),
        DistanceMeters('0.0'),
        Cadence('0'),
        Extensions(
            TPX(
                Speed('0.0'),
            )
        )
    )

    print lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True)
```

This is the current output:

```
<Trackpoint>
  <Time>2017-11-23T20:44:33Z</Time>
  <Postion>
    <LatitudeDegrees>32.2996560</LatitudeDegrees>
    <LongitudeDegrees>-64.7868500</LongitudeDegrees>
  </Postion>
  <AltitudeMeters>16.4</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>0.0</DistanceMeters>
  <Cadence>0</Cadence>
  <Extensions>
    <TPX>
      <Speed>0.0</Speed>
    </TPX>
  </Extensions>
</Trackpoint>
```

Comment: Read [The E-factory](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory), the second example shows usage of `namespace`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the namespace in the ElementMaker. You can also use `None` in the nsmap (namespace map) to make it unprefixed.

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree, builder


def Trackpoint():
    E = builder.ElementMaker()
    AE_E = builder.ElementMaker(namespace="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2",
                                nsmap={None: "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2"})
    Trackpoint = E.Trackpoint
    Time = E.Time
    Postion = E.Postion
    LatitudeDegrees = E.LatitudeDegrees
    LongitudeDegrees = E.LongitudeDegrees
    AltitudeMeters = E.AltitudeMeters
    DistanceMeters = E.DistanceMeters
    Cadence = E.Cadence
    Extensions = E.Extensions
    TPX = AE_E.TPX
    Speed = AE_E.Speed

    the_doc = Trackpoint(
        Time('2017-11-23T20:44:33Z'),
        Postion(
            LatitudeDegrees('32.2996560'),
            LongitudeDegrees('-64.7868500'),
        ),
        AltitudeMeters('16.4'),
        DistanceMeters('0.0'),
        Cadence('0'),
        Extensions(
            TPX(
                Speed('0.0'),
            )
        )
    )

    print etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True)


Trackpoint()
```

Output...

```xml
<Trackpoint>
  <Time>2017-11-23T20:44:33Z</Time>
  <Postion>
    <LatitudeDegrees>32.2996560</LatitudeDegrees>
    <LongitudeDegrees>-64.7868500</LongitudeDegrees>
  </Postion>
  <AltitudeMeters>16.4</AltitudeMeters>
  <DistanceMeters>0.0</DistanceMeters>
  <Cadence>0</Cadence>
  <Extensions>
    <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
      <Speed>0.0</Speed>
    </TPX>
    <Speed>test</Speed>
  </Extensions>
</Trackpoint>
```

Comment: Wonderful, not exactly what I was trying, so I can see why it wasn't working, many thanks.